# Openlayers. Vector tiles, styling features at edges

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, vector-tiles

I'm applying a simple style to a VectorTile layer. The features load and are displayed with said style.

The issue that I'm facing is with the features that fall into the edges (or close to) of the tile appear to be "cut" at the tile limit.

[image]

I've tried to use the `declutter: true` option in the `ol.layer.VectoTile` definition, and this helps but some features dissapear (as if it was making some clustering), and for my use case I need to see all the features even if the icons appear one on top of the other.

[image]

I don't quite understand why this is happening, as the styling is done at the client and not at the server.

Is there a way I can make this work using VectorTiles?

The code I'm using:

```js
const layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    style: vectorStyle,
    //declutter: true,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url: `https://<geoserver_host>/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/${layer_name}@${matrix_set}@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf`,
    }),
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

---

Further information:
The source data is stored in a PostgreSQL database with the PostGIS extension. And GeoServer generates the vector tiles and delivers them trough the TMS service

---

Edit:
I found that the issue was caused because the default style of the layer was a custom one that uses a external image for the icon:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>icon</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Icon</Title>

      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>          
            <PointSymbolizer>
                <Graphic>
                    <ExternalGraphic>
                        <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://<host_url>/${icon_type}/${level}.png" />
                        <Format>image/png</Format>
                    </ExternalGraphic>
                    <Size>24</Size>
                </Graphic>
            </PointSymbolizer>
          </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Setting the default style to the default "point" solved the issue. But I'm not sure why as when using the Vector Tiles it will not use the default server style, but the one provided by the client
Can someone explain why this happens with GeoServer?

Comment: see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8775

Comment: Thanks. But how exactly can I make sure that "Neighbouring tiles need to repeat points that are close to the edge of a tile" ?

Comment: If you are producing your own tiles make sure they have a buffer overlapping the adjacent tiles https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/#encoding-geometry

Comment: The tiles are generated by GeoServer with PostGis as a data store. The tiles are retrieved using the TMS service. I'm updating the post with this details